# How can I use openpyxl to create a list out of the rows in an excel sheet and then insert them into a dictionary?

Tags: excel, list, dictionary, openpyxl

I have a 2X4 table of numbers in excel like this:

```
0.454   0.253
0.345   0.768
0.853   0.098
0.948   0.593
```

I would like to convert each row of that into a separate list and assign that list as a value in a dictionary where the keys are the number of the row. So the dictionary would be:

```
{1: (0.454, 0.253), 2: (0.345, 0.768), 3: (0.853, 0.098), 4: (0.948, 0.593)}
```

I am at a loss as to how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A dictionary keyed by row number is essentially what openpyxl provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. **Keep in mind you will need to swap "ws" for whatever you named your worksheet and load the proper workbook**. I have everything explained inside the code below.. but I'll explain up here as well.

This creates a dictionary, then uses a for loop which will grab the values from the spreadsheet. These values will be added into a list, and that list then placed into the initial dictionary under a new key, which the key will match the row used!

```
    #Loading workbook and initializing the sheet
    wb = load_workbook("tax log1.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active

    #Creates empty dictionary - Loop below adds values
    cell_row_dict = {}
    
    #Loops through first 4 rows 
    for y in range(1, 5): 
        #Getting Values from spreadsheet
        value_to_add1 = ws.cell(row=y, column=1).value 
        value_to_add2 = ws.cell(row=y, column=2).value 

        #This creates a list of the values in the column and also clears it out to ready for nxt loop
        list = []
        list.append(value_to_add1)   
        list.append(value_to_add2)
        
        #Adds the newly created list to a new key.. which will be Y as thats how many rows  are used. 
        cell_row_dict.update({y:list})

    #Print final dictionary - Success!!
    print(cell_row_dict)
```

**If you end up having a lot more columns for whatever reason, I would suggest using more loops to append the list, and get the values.**